# How to create a new Java file by namespace in VS Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code and Java 21 (plus Gradle and Spring Boot, if it matters):

**The procedure I would like to perform:**

1. I manually (or with assistance of AI) write import:

```
import com.example.subpackage.entity.MyNotYetExistingEntity
```

2. The namespace is red underlined, because the class/interface doesn't exist yet.
3. While my cursor in somewhere on the red underlined import, i trigger **"Quick Fix..."** menu with shortcut. ( - I know how to.)
4. (I don't know how to do this:) Now I would select something like "Create new file (by namespace)"
5. I would be prompted, If I would want to create class/interface/enum... New file **MyNotYetExistingEntity.java** would be created. It would be automatically placed in `ProjectFolder/src/java/com/example/subpackage/entity/`. Newly created file would look like this:

```
package com.example.subpackage.entity;

public class MyNotYetExistingEntity {  // or 'interface' instead of 'class', for example

}
```

If you have only alternative solutions, I would like to know them too. But as a lazy programmer, I am focused on efficiency, so I want to perform this action rapidly and without too many extra clicks.

Among others, I have these extension enabled:

- vscjava.vscode-java-pack
- richardwillis.vscode-gradle-extension-pack
- redhat.java

And none of these provides me the desired shortcut.

Comment: you can use the extension I made: [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions) then you can create your own Quick Fixes

Comment: By "namespace" do you mean "package"?

Comment: By "namespace" I mean package declaration with class name: "com.example.subpackage.entity.MyNotYetExistingEntity"

Comment: If you have a clear need, you can report your idea at GitHub. https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/new